hash seems to be changing every time toga app is run
I'm trying to make a password manager app using toga as a Christmas present for my dad. I want to make it so that you can have multiple users on one device, and one users saved passwords are completely separate from another users passwords. I am able to create a username and assign that username a password and hash it. But, whenever I try to login, it doesn't work. Here is the code I use to turn the password (either when you login, or when you create an account), into a hash:
    def encrypt_password(self, password: str):
        print(password)

        password_salt = os.urandom(64)

        pbkdf2_hashed_password = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", password.encode(),
                                                     password_salt, 16).hex()

        self.sha1_hashed_password.update(pbkdf2_hashed_password.encode())

        self.sha224_hashed_password.update(self.sha1_hashed_password.hexdigest().encode())

        self.sha_256_hashed_password.update(self.sha224_hashed_password.hexdigest().encode())

        sha_3_hashed_password = hashlib.sha384()
        sha_3_hashed_password.update(self.sha_256_hashed_password.hexdigest().encode())

        self.sha5_hashed_password.update(sha_3_hashed_password.hexdigest().encode())

        self.md5_hashed_password.update(self.sha5_hashed_password.hexdigest().encode())

        return self.md5_hashed_password

Here is where I create the username:
    async def create_user(self, *args):
        username = self.username_entry.value
        password = self.password_entry.value

        if not os.path.exists(f"{self.app_data}"):
            os.mkdir(self.app_data)

        if not os.path.exists(f"{self.users_folder}{username}"):
            os.mkdir(f"{self.users_folder}{username}")

            with open(f"{self.users_folder}{username}/..data.json", mode="w") as passwords_file:
                encrypted_password = self.encrypt_password(password)

                password_data = {
                    "username_password": encrypted_password.hexdigest()
                }

                json.dump(password_data, passwords_file, indent=4)

        else:
            await self.main_window.dialog(
                toga.ErrorDialog(
                    title=self.error_title,
                    message=f"A user named {username} already exists"
                )
            )

And here is where I try to login:
    def login(self, *args):
        username = self.username_entry.value
        password = self.password_entry.value

        if os.path.exists(f"{self.users_folder}/{username}"):
            encrypted_password = self.encrypt_password(password)

            with open(f"{self.users_folder}{username}/..data.json") as password_file:
                saved_password = json.load(password_file)
                saved_password["username_password"]= saved_password["username_password"]

            print(saved_password["username_password"])
            print(encrypted_password)
            print(type(saved_password["username_password"]))

            print(encrypted_password == saved_password["username_password"])

            if encrypted_password == saved_password["username_password"]:
                self.main_box.clear()
                self.main_box.add(toga.Label(text=f"Successfully logged in as {username}"))
            else:
                self.main_box.add(toga.Label(text="Login failed"))
        else:
            self.main_box.add(toga.Label(text="Login failed"))

I tried using to built-in function hash, but it still didn't work. I also tried various things, like converting the hashed password to a string before saving the hashed password when I created a user, trying to convert it to a dictionary using dict, I even tried adding the hash itself, without the hexidecimal part, but that just errored out saying that type HASH wasn't json serializable

Password hashing usually uses a salt, which changes each time you encrypt. The salt is saved with the hashed password, you have to use the same salt when checking the password.

Don't implement your own authentication code. Use an existing library, it will take care of all this automatically.

Creating your own password manager for a Christmas gift is like building a plane instead of buying an air ticket. If you knew how to do it well, you’d not be here. Do your father a favor, and buy him a subscription to a reputable password manager.

@Barmar What do you mean by authentication code? Where am I implementing it? What is an authentication code? Sorry if these are dumb questions, but I didn't understand the docs really at all

I might have misunderstood, I thought that's what the login() function was trying to do.

What's the point of this line saved_password["username_password"]= saved_password["username_password"]? Setting a variable to itself doesn't do anything.

Each time you call encrypt_password() it generates a new salt with password_salt = os.urandom(64). So there will be a different salt when you save create the user than when you login.

@Barmar Thanks. It's working now. That was it. saved_password["username_password"]= saved_password["username_password"] was leftover from some debugging I did, and forgot to remove. Thanks for pointing that out too
